# Find a simpler expression for $A = \mathbb{Q} \setminus \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \left (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{2n\} \right )$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am told to give a simpler expression for the following set $A$, and prove it.
$$ A = \mathbb{Q} \setminus \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \left (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{2n\} \right )$$

The book gives an "element chasing" approach, while I did the following which I'd like to know is valid/correct.

*Claim*: $A = 2\mathbb{Z}$ (the set of all even integers)

*Proof*:
First, from the DeMorgan's law (proven earlier), the second term can be expressed as
$$\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \left (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{2n\} \right) = \mathbb{R} \setminus \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \{2n\} = \mathbb{R} \setminus 2\mathbb{Z}$$

So,
$$
\begin{align}
    A &= \mathbb{Q} \setminus (\mathbb{R} \setminus 2\mathbb{Z}) \\
      &= \mathbb{Q} \setminus \left (\mathbb{R} \cap (2\mathbb{Z})^C \right ) \\
      &= \mathbb{Q} \cap (\mathbb{R}^C \cup 2\mathbb{Z}) \tag{By defn. of setdiff and DeMorgan's law} \\
      &= \mathbb{Q} \cap \left (\emptyset \cup 2\mathbb{Z}\right ) \\
      &= \mathbb{Q} \cap 2\mathbb{Z} \\
      &= 2\mathbb{Z}
\end{align}
$$

My only hesitation is where I take $\mathbb{R}^C$ to be $\emptyset$; while the problem doesn't state the universe to be $\mathbb{R}$, we haven't dealt with anything other than $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{N}$) in the book yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The universe just has to be "big enough" to contain all the sets that you might encounter in a particular problem. In fact, you can take the universe to be the universe $\mathcal{U}$ of all sets (which is not a set but a proper class), but it does not affect the result.
$$A=\mathbb{Q} \cap (\mathbb{R}^C \cup 2\mathbb{Z})=(\mathbb{Q} \cap\mathbb{R}^C )\cup (\mathbb{Q} \cap 2\mathbb{Z})
\\=(\mathbb{Q} \cap \{x\in \mathcal{U}\mid x \notin \mathbb{R}\})\cup 2\mathbb{Z}=\emptyset\cup 2 \mathbb{Z}=2 \mathbb{Z}$$